# Using prestashop app from script located outside prestashop folder

Tags: prestashop

I would like to use the prestashop app from a php script (external_script.php) located outside prestashop folder but still on the same server.

I could do that with Magento using :

```
    require_once external_folder/magento/app/Mage.php;
```

I've tried to include *prestashop/config/config.inc.php* and *prestashop/init.php* but it redirects *external_script.php* to prestashop *index.php*

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

STEF

Answer (score 8):

Add the following 2 lines at the start of your PHP script and then you can use all the classes and functions of PrestaShop:

```
include(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../config/config.inc.php');
include(_PS_ROOT_DIR_.'/init.php');
```

Also, include the main class file whose functions you want to call in the external script, it must be some of your module's file. For example:

```
include_once(__PATH__TO__CLASS__FILE__.'/xyzmodule.php');
```

After adding the above codes to include required files you can simply create objects of the class file you want to call and use its code. For example:

```
$xObj = new Xyzmodule();
$xObj->callingXFunction();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Also to get module you can use $module = Module::getInstanceByName($name);

Answer (score 1):

Magento is a well structured Zend project and it's easy to bootstrap the app to use it outside HTTP front controller, PrestaShop is another story it's really a big mess of spaghetti code, to bootstrap the app really depends os PS version and in some cases on installed modules that changes core behaviour.

To start you can first include the config/config.inc.php file that is on PS root dir, this will init the PS classloader and a bunch of configuration defines, if you use another autoloader and a old version on PS (<1.6) you need to workaround it, this is a simple bootstrap code that allow make any PS call:

```
    <?php
// Load PS config and autoloader
define ('PS_DIR', __DIR__ . '/../ps-wtf');
require_once PS_DIR .'/config/config.inc.php';

// I use this to load compoper dependencies
require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

// Call old __autoload() if present, required for PrestaShop old versions
if (function_exists('__autoload')) {
    spl_autoload_register(function ($className) {
        __autoload($className);
    });
}

// Init Shop context, required some operation will fail without it
// adust accordly to multistore PS >= 1.6
Shop::setContext(Shop::CONTEXT_ALL);

// Init PS context, some modules require that this context was initialized and with correct data
// some core function fired in the admin require at least a employee
define ('PS_DEFAULT_EMPLOYEE', 1);
$psContext = Context::getContext();
if (!$psContext->employee) {
    $psContext->employee = new Employee(PS_DEFAULT_EMPLOYEE);
}

// You can make any API call
$cat = new Category();
$cat->name = [
    1 => 'New',
    2 => 'Nuevo',
];
$cat->id_parent = 1;
$cat->save();

echo $cat->id;
```

Some PS functionality depends on correct initialization of some core classes (Yes it's crazy), you can take a look at ControllerCore and FrontControllerCore to see what is happening in the normal PS request flow.

I hope that this can help.

Answer (score 0):

The way prestashop is designed won't let you do this kind of thing easily.
I think your best bet is to use their web service API : http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Using+the+PrestaShop+Web+Service

There is a PHP client library for this : https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop-webservice-lib/blob/master/PSWebServiceLibrary.php

You can also use curl, but be warned : they use a lot of different tokens on differents pages, this is quite annoying.

Here is some bash code to log yourself in, grab some tokens and upload an import file. You can adapt it to PHP curl and do anything else you want :

```
r=$(curl -k -c cookies -b cookies -s --request POST -d "ajax=1&token=&controller=AdminLogin&submitLogin=1&passwd=[YOU_PASSWORD_URL_ENCODED]&email=[YOUR_EMAIl_URL_ENCODED]" 'https://[YOUR_PRESTASHOP_HOST_OR_LOCALHOST]/[YOUR_PRESTASHOP_ADMIN_DIR]/index.php')
token=$(echo $r | sed -n 's/.*token=\([0-9a-zA-Z]*\).*/\1/gp')

admin_token=$(curl -k -c cookies -b cookies 'https://[YOUR_PRESTASHOP_HOST_OR_LOCALHOST]/[YOUR_PRESTASHOP_ADMIN_DIR]/index.php?controller=AdminDashboard&token='"$token" | sed -n '0,/.*?_token=\([-_0-9a-zA-Z]*\).*/s/.*?_token=\([-_0-9a-zA-Z]*\).*/\1/p')


brand_file_name=$(curl -k -c cookies -b cookies -F 'file=@local_path_of_a_file.xlsx' 'https://[YOUR_PRESTASHOP_HOST_OR_LOCALHOST]/[YOUR_PRESTASHOP_ADMIN_DIR]/index.php/configure/advanced/import/file/upload?_token='"$admin_token" | sed -nE 's/.*"name":"([^"]*).*/\1/gp')
```